# Swift Error - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT for setValuesForKeys

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
        if let dictionary = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary.)
            print(user.name!, user.email!)

        }
    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

When adding data from my firebase database to my app, it throws a SIGABRT error when adding the information from a dictionary to my array of users( Which I created an object for). What is the issue with what I am doing?

The error message in the log says this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ChatApp.User 0x10bdeec70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18136a364 0x1805b0528 0x18136a02c 0x181c82630 0x181d1e7dc 0x100016170 0x10001645c 0x10016dd7c 0x100199524 0x1012a92cc 0x1012a928c 0x1012adea0 0x181312544 0x181310120 0x18122fe58 0x1830dcf84 0x18a8af67c 0x100025fbc 0x180d4c56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please read the exception reason. It's most likely *this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XYZ*. XYZ is the key in your class which does not match the dictionary. By the way: There are better ways than KVC `setValuesForKeys` in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your keys in your database don't match the variable names in your User object class. You can avoid this by doing it manually yourself like so:

```
    let reference = Database.database().reference()
    reference.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        guard let username = dictionary["username"] as? String else { return }

        let user = User()
        user.username = username
        // do this for everything the user object needs to hold.

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: warning in Xcode conditional cast from FFIRDataSnapshot to unrelated type [String: AnyObject] always fails